# How can I center multiple <article> elements vertically in a responsive design?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

i whant to center my article classes in my aside verticaly. If the size of the browser window is changed or is smaller (like on a mobile phone), the centering should adjust accordingly and the template should be responsive.

By the way: I talk about my three "war-boxes", that you could recognize with the words "Gegner 1", "Gegner 2" "and the gray background around them.. If the screen width is greater than or equal to 1200px, the Articles shall stand side by side, if the resolution is smaller, they should adapt dynamically and are available on a mobile phone resolution among themselves.

How could I do that?

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<title>Funfighter Alliance</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/include/designs/FFA/reset.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/include/designs/FFA/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="/include/designs/FFA/js/modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="/include/designs/FFA/js/respond.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<!--Header mit Navigation-->
<header id="side-header-wrapper">
  <section id="side-header"> 
    <!--Logo + Logounterschrift-->
    <a href="http://funfighteralliance.de"><img alt="Funfighter Alliance - Offizielle Projekt-Homepage" src="/include/designs/FFA/bilder/Logo-FFA.jpg"></a>
    <p>Offizielle Projekt-Homepage</p>
    <!--Navigation-->
    <nav>
      <h2 class="hidden">Navigation</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Teams</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Forum</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Kontakt</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </section>
  </header>

<!--Spacer mit Log-In-->
<section id="spacer">
  <h2 class="hidden">Log-In</h2>
  <div class="login">{_boxes_VTEC-LOGINH}</div>
</section>

<!--3 Boxen für den War-Content-->
<aside>
<h2 class="hidden">Our Matches</h2>
<!--Topmatch Team 1-->
<article>
<img class="topwar_picleft" alt="Logo 1" src="/include/images/teams/team1.png" />
<p class="bluebox_versus">versus</p>
<img class="topwar_picright" alt="Logo 2" src="/include/images/teams/team1.png" />
<div class="topwar_whitebox">
<p class="whitebox_teamleft">Gegner links</p>
<p class="whitebox_versus">VERSUS</p>
<p class="whitebox_teamright">Gegner links</p>
</div>
</article>
<!--Topmatch Team 2-->
<article>
<img class="topwar_picleft" alt="Logo 1" src="/include/images/teams/team1.png" />
<p class="bluebox_versus">versus</p>
<img class="topwar_picright" alt="Logo 2" src="/include/images/teams/team1.png" />
<div class="topwar_whitebox">
<p class="whitebox_teamleft">Gegner links</p>
<p class="whitebox_versus">VERSUS</p>
<p class="whitebox_teamright">Gegner links</p>
</div>
</article>
<!--Last Matches-->
<article>
<img class="topwar_picleft" alt="Logo 1" src="/include/images/teams/team1.png" />
<p class="bluebox_versus">versus</p>
<img class="topwar_picright" alt="Logo 2" src="/include/images/teams/team1.png" />
<div class="topwar_whitebox">
<p class="whitebox_teamleft">Gegner links</p>
<p class="whitebox_versus">VERSUS</p>
<p class="whitebox_teamright">Gegner links</p>
</div>
</article>
<br class="clear" />
</aside>

<!--Content mit dynamischen Inhalt (je nach Unterseite generiert)-->
<div id="post"> {EXPLODE}</div>

<!--Footer, am Ende der Seite-->
<footer> </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/*Allgemeine Definitionen*/
body {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-top: 5px solid #009CFF;
    color: #272934;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: relative;
}
p {
    line-height: 25px;
    margin: 5px 0;
}
a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color 0.5s ease 0s;
}
strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}
img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.hidden {
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
    position: absolute;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
/*Header*/
#side-header {
    color: #444444;
    font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
}
#side-header-wrapper {
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #E8E8E8 0%, #FFFFFF 100%);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    height: 81px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
#side-header p {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left: 107.5px;
}
/*Navigation*/
nav {
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
nav ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 3px 15px;
}
/*Spacer m. Login*/
#spacer {
    color: #444444;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 70px;
    position: relative;
}
.login {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
/*War-Boxes*/

.topwar_bluebox {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #009CFF;
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 95px;
    margin-right: 45px;
    width: 256px;
}
aside {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #808080;
    margin: 70px auto 45px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    width: auto;
}
aside article {
    width: 256px;
    margin-right: 45px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.bluebox_versus {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
    height: 22px;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin: 40px 0 0 12px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 46px;
}
.topwar_picleft {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 22px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    width: 72px;
}
.topwar_picright {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 22px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    width: 72px;
}
.topwar_whitebox {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 45px;
    width: 256px;
}

.whitebox_teamleft {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 22px;
    max-width: 72px;
}
.whitebox_versus {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEF1;
    color: #2099DC;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
    height: 14px;
    line-height: 14px;
    margin: 10px 0 0 13px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 44px;
}
.whitebox_teamright {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 22px;
    max-width: 72px;
}
/*Content*/
#post {
    clear: both;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
}
/*News*/
#news_headline {
    border-top: 2px solid #009CFF;
    max-width: 1200px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    padding-top: 14px;
}
.news_headline_kate {
    background-color: #00A3FF;
    float: left;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 15px;
    line-height: 15px;
    max-width: 48px;
    text-align: center;
}
.news_headline_title, .news_headline_title_1 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: -3.5px;
    max-width: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 48px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.news_headline_title_1 {
    max-width: 470px;
}
img.news_headline_writersgraphic {
    height: 16px;
    margin-top: -3.5px;
    max-width: 17px;
    position: absolute;
}
.news_headline_username {
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-left: 18px;
    margin-top: -1px;
    position: absolute;
}
.news_headline_datum {
    color: #858A9F;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-left: 171px;
    margin-top: -1px;
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#news_content {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
}
#news_footer {
    max-width: 1200px;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    padding-top: 14px;
    position: relative;
}
a.news_headline_comment {
    background-color: #272934;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 17px;
    line-height: 17px;
    max-width: 48px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    top: 7px;
}
#news_headline, #news_content {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #009CFF;
}
/*Footer*/
footer {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #333333;
    clear: both;
    height: 350px;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
}
```

Link to jsfiddle-example of my code: [Click me](http://jsfiddle.net/Jmg9y/)

Answer (score 0):

A way of vertically center that is also responsive is to use [Flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) even if it is not fully supported by all the browsers yet and it does not work on old browsers ([ref](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)).